# Error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './1695556319341.mp3']

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an mp4 file to an mp3 file and then directly upload it to Firebase storage without saving it locally in my machine, How can I do that currently I'm getting an error when I try to do that the error is "Error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './1695556319341.mp3']" How can i fix this issue with my Node.js code and make things work?

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";
import serviceAccount from '../firebase/serviceAccountKey';
import { path as ffmpegPath } from '@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg';
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import { readFile, unlink } from 'fs/promises';

initializeApp(serviceAccount);
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

async function convertMP4ToMP3AndUploadToFirebase(inputPath: any, firebaseStoragePath: any) {
    const date = Date.now();
    const outputPath = `./${date}.mp3`;

    try {
        await ffmpeg(inputPath)
            .output(outputPath)
            .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
            .format('mp3')
            .run();

        const storage = getStorage();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, firebaseStoragePath);

        const fileBuffer = await readFile(outputPath);
        const metadata = { contentType: 'audio/mpeg' };
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fileBuffer, metadata);
        const snapshot = await uploadTask;
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
        await unlink(outputPath);

        console.log('MP4 file converted to MP3 and uploaded to Firebase Storage successfully!');
        console.log('Download URL:', downloadURL);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

const inputPath = './video.mp4';
const date = Date.now();
const firebaseStoragePath = `./${date}.mp3`;

convertMP4ToMP3AndUploadToFirebase(inputPath, firebaseStoragePath);
```

Comment: are you sure `ffmpeg` run sucessfully and created that file specified in `outputpath`?

Comment: Looks like the `ffmpeg()` process is failing to create your output file.

Comment: @derpirscher Maybe can you tell how do i upload them directly to firebase instead of saving it?

Comment: currently, i get that error but it does after 1 second  generate a mp3 file like 1695561309749.mp3

Comment: I don't know, because I neither use ffmpeg nor firebase. It was a more general advice to check if the file really exists. Furthermore as I don't know that ffmpeg library, is it really promise-based? Because if `ffmpeg...run()` doesn't return a promise, you cannot `await` it and your code will try to read the file before it's written ...

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Functions, you can't write files anywhere except /tmp.  You should know that the /tmp filesystem is entirely in memory, so if you write a large file there, you could run out of memory if the server instance isn't configured with enough memory to handle it.

I suggest reviewing the documentation and other resources about this:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#memory-file-system
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#always_delete_temporary_files
- [Create a file in the Cloud Functions / temp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687815/create-a-file-in-the-cloud-functions-temp-directory)