# Download file from cloud storage into cloud function temporarily

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Having a hell of a time getting this to work. I wrote a cloud function to create PDFs. The PDFs can have images that are downloaded from cloud storage. All of this is not publicly accessible and all permissions are fine.

I'm able to see the metadata of the file I'm attempting to download, but the actual act of downloading to the filesystem temporarily is where I'm stuck. What I get is an empty array: [].

```
  const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  functions.http('<my func>', async (req, res) => {
       const bucketName = '<my bucket>';
       const fileName = 'mytest.jpg';
       const cwd = path.join(__dirname, '..');
       const destFileName = path.join(cwd, 'tmp/mytest.jpg');

       const options = {
            destination: destFileName
       }

       const [meta] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getMetadata();
       console.log(meta) <-- this is populated with the files metadata
       
       const file = await 
           storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);
       console.log(file) <-- this is always []
      
       ....
 }
```

I've tried a few things I've seen in other posts with createReadStream()/createWriteStream() but no dice there either, namely because file is an empty array.

The above code is taken from the docs here: [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/samples/downloadFile.js) and [Here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/)

Thanks in advance for some guidance

Comment: Any error? I guess that you are missing permission to read the bucket. Maybe try to download the file using the cloud console first. Ideally, you should use the service account which attached to your cloud function

Comment: No error. I am using a service account, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this code isn't correct for Cloud Functions:

```
       const cwd = path.join(__dirname, '..');
       const destFileName = path.join(cwd, 'tmp/mytest.jpg');
```

The only writable directory in Cloud Functions is the temp directory, which is available in `os.tmpdir()`. It's likely going to be "/tmp".  See: [Create a file in the Cloud Functions / temp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687815/create-a-file-in-the-cloud-functions-temp-directory)

Secondly, the result you're getting from [download()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download) is expected.  The returned [DownloadResponse](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#DownloadResponse) is an array with an single optional item with the contents of the download. Since you're telling the SDK to download to a destination file, I'd expect that array to be empty - it's not an error for it to be that way.  Your code should continue as if the file has been created with the contents from the download.

Comment: The writeable locations have changed, you can now write to most locations except for the directory containing your source files and some OS files. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#memory-file-system. The local write in OP's code still won't work, but it's not just `/tmp` anymore. :)

Comment: So basically what your saying is download() is actually performing the action of downloading the file to my destination attribute...I'm not going far enough and opening the file and checking it's actually there?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be making an assumption about the result of the download without specific evidence to back it up (the call didn't explicitly fail, and you haven't checked if the file actually exists).

Comment: Thanks! And for the pointer to the docs.

Comment: Just tested that was the issue. Following instructions from your link to the download() https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download functions docs I was able to download the file to memory and view its contents. Thanks!